# How can i merge 3 sql select queries in single query?

Tags: mysql

I am using this query

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT tr.object_id, p.post_title, p.comment_count
   FROM wpug_term_relationships AS tr
   LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p ON p.post_parent = tr.object_id
   WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id =122 
   ORDER BY tr.object_id DESC 
  ) AS Column1,  

  (SELECT tr.object_id, p.guid, p.post_type
  FROM wpug_term_relationships AS tr
  LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p ON p.post_parent = tr.object_id
  WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id =122 AND p.post_type='attachment' 
  ORDER BY tr.object_id DESC 
  ) AS Column2, 

  (SELECT tr.object_id, p.meta_value, p.meta_key
   FROM wpug_term_relationships AS tr
   LEFT JOIN wpug_postmeta AS p ON p.post_id = tr.object_id
   WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id =122 AND p.meta_key IN ('rehub_views', 'rehub_offer_product_price') 
   ORDER BY tr.object_id DESC 
  ) AS Column3
```

Comment: You want 3 columns?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what you expect the result to be. Are the three sub-selects that you use guaranteed to 0 or 1 rows?

Comment: Your subselects does not return the single-column results so it is a bit weird to alias them as `ColumnX`. They are rather to be named `TempTableX`. The other complication is that all three subselects returns the columns of different types. And the worst thing is that all three `JOIN`s uses different conditions. As for me that is the kind of `XY-problem` and you have to revise your approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you move part of the WHERE statements into the join you can accomplish the same thing:

```
SELECT tr.object_id, 
    p.post_title, p.comment_count,
    p2.guid, p2.post_type,
    pm.meta_value, pm.meta_key
FROM wpug_term_relationships AS tr
    LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p ON p.post_parent = tr.object_id
    LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p2 ON p2.post_parent = tr.object_id
        AND pm.post_type='attachment' 
    LEFT JOIN wpug_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = tr.object_id 
        AND pm.meta_key IN ('rehub_views', 'rehub_offer_product_price') 
WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id=122 
ORDER BY tr.object_id DESC
```

I noticed that on the first join to wpug_posts you don't filter `post_type` but on the second one you do.  I assume this means it will return multiple rows.  Do you want the first one to return `post_type='attachment'` as well?  If not you'll need to add `AND p.post_type<>'attachment'` to the first join

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked it but you can try it on this way, fetching all records on a single query and then use a CASE statement to select the correct object_id.

```
SELECT    CASE WHEN p.post_type <> 'attachment'
               AND  p.meta_key NOT IN ('rehub_views', 'rehub_offer_product_price') tr.object_id
          END AS object_id_c1, 
          p1.post_title AS post_title_c1, 
          p1.comment_count AS comment_count_c1,
          CASE WHEN p.post_type = 'attachment'
               AND  p.meta_key NOT IN ('rehub_views', 'rehub_offer_product_price') tr.object_id
          END AS object_id_c2,
          p2.post_title AS post_title_c2, 
          p2.comment_count AS comment_count_c2,
          CASE WHEN p.post_type <> 'attachment'
               AND  p.meta_key IN ('rehub_views', 'rehub_offer_product_price') tr.object_id
          END AS object_id_c3,
          p3.post_title AS post_title_c3,  
          p3.comment_count AS comment_count_c3,
FROM      wpug_term_relationships AS tr
LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p1 
ON        p.post_parent = tr.object_id
AND       tr.term_taxonomy_id = 122
LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p2 
ON        p.post_parent = tr.object_id
AND       tr.term_taxonomy_id = 122
AND       p.post_type = 'attachment'
LEFT JOIN wpug_posts AS p3
ON        p.post_parent = tr.object_id
AND       tr.term_taxonomy_id = 122
AND       p.meta_key IN ('rehub_views', 'rehub_offer_product_price')
ORDER BY  tr.object_id DESC;
```

You could also use a single left join and a case statement for each column.